# Code optimization for processing multiple txt files (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to optimize my code. I need to process 150 000 text files and extract id from file title. I also need to extract only words from Detected text field. My code is working but it's taking a very long time. I would need some faster solution like parallel jobs or something similar but I don't know how to implement this kind of solutions.

My code:

```
# folder with multiple text files

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "text_files", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path, encoding="utf8") as f_input:
        pathPre = file_path[:file_path.find(".")]
        pathFinal = pathPre[pathPre.rfind("\\")+1:]
        ID= "ID: " + pathFinal + "\n----------\n"
        corpus.append(ID + f_input.read())


df = pd.DataFrame(corpus) 
df_txt = df[0].str.split('\n', expand=True)
df_txt[0] = df_txt[0].str.partition('_')[0].str.strip()

listOfLists = []

for index, row in df_txt.iterrows():
    detectedTextIter = []
    for i in range (12115):
        if (row[i] is None):
            continue
        else:
            if ("ID: " in row[i]):
                ID = row[i].split("ID: ", 1)[1]
                detectedTextIter.append(ID)
            elif ("Detected Text:" in row[i]):
                detectedText = row[i].split("Detected Text:", 1)[1]
                detectedTextIter.append(detectedText)
            else:
                continue
    listOfLists.append(detectedTextIter)

newDF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listOfLists)

IDList = []

for index, row in newDF.iterrows():
    ID= row[0]
    IDlist.append(ID)

uniqueIDList = list(set(IDList))

keywordListofLists = []

for i in uniqueIDList:
    newList = []
    newList.append(i)
    keywordList = []
    newList.append(keywordList)
    keywordListofLists.append(newList)

for i in listOfLists:
    IDLookup = i[0]
    words = []
    
    for k in range(1, len(i)):
        words.append(i[k])
    
    for j in range(len(keywordListofLists)):
        if (keywordListofLists[j][0] == IDLookup):
            
            for x in words:
                keywordListofLists[j][1].append(x)

for i in keywordListofLists:
    wordList = i[1]
    uniqueWords = list(set(wordList))
    i[1] = uniqueWords

UniqueKeywordPerUniqueIDList = pd.DataFrame.from_records(keywordListofLists)
UniqueKeywordPerUniqueIDList.columns = ['id','text']
ML_df = UniqueKeywordPerUniqueIDList.text.apply(pd.Series).merge(UniqueKeywordPerUniqueIDList, left_index = True, right_index = True).drop(['text'], axis = 1).melt(id_vars = ['id'], value_name = 'text').drop("variable", axis = 1).dropna()
```

My text file:

```
Id: 84194a52-6402-41c8-9057-4fd31a9b2cea
Type: LINE
Detected Text: ORPINE
Confidence: 37.295963
Id: dcfeca0e-1dc2-47e7-8abe-6c4a4309b525
Type: LINE
Detected Text: BOAT SOA
Confidence: 91.334778
Id: 69889983-b22a-4d08-bf3b-841bb1303512
Type: LINE
Detected Text: ORPRODUCTS
Confidence: 96.001930
Id: 67c9a54a-f8c0-4217-8764-d288842ad3a1
Type: LINE
Detected Text: PRESH
Confidence: 38.313396
Id: bddd43e2-b284-40fb-ae0b-6d91c3f41cc3
Type: WORD
Detected Text: ORPINE
Confidence: 37.295963
Id: 7f55b98d-e2eb-4e38-a517-79a45aff5a94
Type: WORD
Detected Text: BOAT
Confidence: 99.360634
Id: 52309976-6dcd-4727-98d4-fc24640f98ae
Type: WORD
Detected Text: SOA
Confidence: 83.308922
Id: 50c1f5b2-a2e2-470e-b823-9ed9b8059ea3
Type: WORD
Detected Text: ORPRODUCTS
Confidence: 96.001930
Id: aa7b9b69-8f8e-49e6-bd63-b26e8f7a3d08
Type: WORD
Detected Text: PRESH
Confidence: 38.313396
```

Comment: We need data not just code. Please post sample of text and desired result of one file for a [mcve]. As rule of thumb, `iterrows` should be avoided with pandas data frame processing. Unclear what all these loops are doing.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Since you know that there are solutions out there, but you're not familiar with them, the next step is to do your appropriate research.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You should do some timing analysis to find out where the time is spent to help determine where your optimization efforts should be concentrated.

Comment: Please remove that "magic number" of  12115 in range.

Comment: Use `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0]` to get your key.

Comment: @Parfait In my code I'm trying to process textfiles and for each file I'm extracting id from the name of the file. 
Example would be file name BG6789_hgjgjfnfnf, I'm extracting everithing before underscore so in this exaple my id is BG6789. 
My wanted output is to create a data frame with two columns id and text. 
In the text column I need only words from the Detected Text:

My text file looks like this:

```
Id: 84194a52-6402-41c8-9057-4fd31a9b2cea
Type: LINE
Detected Text: ORPINE
Confidence: 37.295963
Id: dcfeca0e-1dc2-47e7-8abe-6c4a4309b525
Type: LINE
Detected Text: BOAT 
```

Comment: @RufusVS the reason why I'm using my magic number 12115 is because i have 12115 columns in my DataFrame.

Comment: @Prune I did my research but none of the solutions I found worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225954/discussion-between-dinko-jantos-and-rufusvs).

Answer (score 1):

Simply directly read your text file using the `:` as delimiter. Then subset data frame to only keep `Detected Text` rows. Use `assign` to add needed column. Wrap everything in a list comprehension with chained pandas calls.

```py
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "text_files", "*.txt"))

# BUILD LIST OF DFs WITH LIST COMPREHENSION
df_list = [(pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=":", header=0, names=['key', 'text'])   # IMPORT COLON-SEPARATED TEXT FILE
             .query("key=='Detected Text'")                                    # SUBSET DF FOR NEEDED ROWS   
             .drop(['key'], axis='columns')                                    # DROP UNNEEDED COLUMN
             .assign(id = os.join.basename(file_path).split('_')[0])           # EXTRACT STRING BEFORE UNDERSCORE
             .reindex(['id', 'text'], axis='columns')                          # RE-ORDER COLUMNS
           ) for file_path in file_list]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)                               # VERTICALLY STACK ALL DFs
```

Comment: I have syntaxerror -> *) for file_path in file_list]*  but I will try to fix that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like I had an extra parenthesis with `assign` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could read them all by using pandas and glob. Take a look at this example:

With the help of glob, we can read all txt and put them into a single dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
txts = sorted(glob('*.txt'))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file, sep=',') for file in txts),ignore_index=True)
```

And for the case of extracting id and the other things, you might use regex and nltk

Comment: This loses the association of the file name to the data lines.